# record camera input in android/openCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I'm a newbie in anything openCV related and I need some guidance with a simple android app I want to build. basically, I want to write a small app that buffers e.g. 30 seconds of video (with my android phone camera as an input), and save those last 30 seconds in a file when the user press a button.

I know this can easily be done with only android sdk, but I want to do it using openCV as this app will be used for further development.

hope you guys can help me out!

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to develop applications with OpenCV on Android. Check the **Download** section on [this page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android) for details.

OpenCV does not provide a buffering mechanism to store the frames, it's up to you to implement it. Read each frame from the camera and store them on a buffer.

If the camera has a framerate of 30 fps, you'll need an array of 900 `IplImage*` to buffer the last 30 seconds of video. A circular buffer might be interesting for that.

Comment: I was hoping OpenCV would have some buffering mechanism for the frames, but this also works for me. Thanks!